# Stats Model gives error and changes my inputs

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

I am sorting a data frame and then inserting it into the statsmodel OLS function. Before I pass my X and Y into the function X looks like this:

[image]

and Y looks like this:

[image]

I then pass it to the mentioned function in the following way:

```
model = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
```

After running this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

In addition, the X and Y matrices are empty when I check them. My questions are: Why am getting this error and why are my matrices being altered?

Comment: most likely that's an error in your code and X, Y is not what you intended it to be. statsmodels never changes y and x.

Comment: If I run the sm.OLS(Y,X).fit() in the next cell (im using jupyter) the function runs correctly and gives a result without error.  In addition both my X and Y are of the same size and have non Nans. @Josef

Comment: Maybe you ran the cells out of order. In any case, this is very likely in the surrounding code, and very very unlikely in statsmodels. You need a full example to see what's happening.